# How to read a public Google doc from a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a public Google doc (available to anyone with the link). I have a Flutter app (web, iPhone, and Android). I'd like to read the Google doc from the Flutter app.

All the documentation seems to be one big web of OAuth 2, login, creating cloud apps, and various things that never seem to come to an answer on how to actually get started.

It seems to me because the Google doc is publicly available that there should be a way to do this without authentication. (Maybe, Google prevents this to protect against bots.)

Is there a snippet of code that shows how to read a Google doc from a Flutter app. (Inclusive everything, many examples I saw suggest that someone has to do authentication first, but I don't know how.)

Comment: the easiest way is to use webview to open that link, if that link return some data , you can parse the body manually and render it with your own ui, if its not , it maybe need auth you can use firebaseauth and ask user to login to read it, or better use jwt from your endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this problem by adding the url_launcher package to your application. You can send any Google document you want in your application to Google's website with the help of a link you assign. You can install the package to the .yaml file from this link: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'); // You can replace it with the url of the Google document you want

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _launchUrl,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
  }
}
```

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

Comment: I'm not trying to show a Google doc in the browser. I'm trying to read the Google doc with code.